# How to sign a JAR file using a .PFX file

Tags: certificate, code-signing, pfx, jar-signing

We sign our .net code with a .PFX cert file. A colleague now needs to use the the same cert to sign a .jar file for a customer.

Can someone point me to a link or an example of how I can do this please?

The jar file will be used on Oracle Web Logic Server running on Solaris.

And, once signed do we need to send out anything other signed jar file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Link updated thanks to @Ezequiel]

https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1207/7/how-to-sign-java-jar-files

Check if you can see the certs

```
-> keytool -list -v -storetype pkcs12 -keystore file.pfx
```

Note the alias.

If it can:
`-> jarsigner -storetype pkcs12 -keystore file.pfx myjar.jar alias`

That's all there is to it.

To verify the signature of the file...

```
-> jarsigner -verify JAR_FILE
```

Where JAR_FILE is the file to be signed.

Comment: Link is no longer working, but I found the new one in case anyone is interested in https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1207/7/how-to-sign-java-jar-files

Comment: @Ezequiel just edit the answer :-)

Comment: I can't do that, it shows 'Suggested edit queue is full'

Comment: @Ezequiel I've updated it for you. Thank for finding the link