# Having Trouble Setting Up Code Signing keystore on linux

Tags: java, linux, code-signing, keystore

I am trying to set up the code signing keystore on our linux build server, and am having trouble doing so.
Background:  We use both Netbeans IDE for developing an application that we release both as a jar file and an exe (with the embedded JRE to avoid any compatibility issues).  Development is done on our Windows 7 PCs, but the build server is hosted on a linux build server.  We use Ant.
Problem:  I need to set up the keystore so that the same Ant build.xml will generate the signed jar file (and exe file) on my PC, as well as being able to generate the same signed jar and exe file on the build server.
I obtained a department pfx file from our IT, as well as an Intermediate and a Root certificate.  These 3 items SHOULD provide the full chain (I think).
I have tried various ways to import these into our linux PC with no luck.
I used openssl to extract the certificate pem and the private key pem from the pfx, and tried to import those into a newly created .keystore file on the linux PC, but still cannot get either jarsigner to sign the jar, or signtool to sign the exe.
when I type: jarsigner -keystore .keystore .jar 
... I get ...
jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: daqkey.  daqkey must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.
How can I verify that a keystore private key has a proper certificate chain?
I've tried the keytool -list command, but I don't know what I am looking for in the resultant output.
Can anyone help?

MORE DETAILS:
after using jarsigner to attempt to sign a jar file, I get these results:
smk     5763 Thu Aug 06 10:54:02 CDT 2015 com/nov/cp/daqconfigtool/resources/log-configuration.xml

```
  X.509, CN="myCompanyName", O="myCompanyName", L=Houston, ST=Texas, C=US (daqkey)
  [certificate is valid from 3/31/15 10:11 AM to 4/1/16 4:18 AM]
  X.509, CN=Entrust Code Signing Certification Authority - L1D, OU="(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc.", OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
  [certificate is valid from 11/11/11 9:29 AM to 11/11/21 9:28 PM]
  X.509, CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048), OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited, OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.), O=Entrust.net
  [certificate is valid from 3/23/09 10:18 AM to 3/23/19 10:48 AM]
  X.509, CN=Entrust.net Secure Server Certification Authority, OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited, OU=www.entrust.net/CPS incorp. by ref. (limits liab.), O=Entrust.net, C=US
  [certificate is valid from 5/25/99 11:09 AM to 5/25/19 11:39 AM]

  [entry was signed on 8/7/15 9:21 AM]
  X.509, CN="myCompanyName", O="myCompanyName", L=Houston, ST=Texas, C=US (daqkey)
  [certificate is valid from 3/31/15 10:11 AM to 4/1/16 4:18 AM]
  [CertPath not validated: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should be able to [sign using the pfx directly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210254/how-to-sign-a-jar-file-using-a-pfx-file).

Comment: I tried you suggestion (or actually the steps in the link).  I did 'seem' to work, and gave me the 'jar verified' response at the command line, but when looking at the properties in the Windows, there was no "Digital Signature" tab.  It didn't get signed.  And it definitely was the same file (I tried it twice to make sure all paths were correct, etc.)

Comment: More info (and more headaches):  I've looked at the contents of our Corporate Department's *.pfx file.  It contains one PrivateKeyEntry and a 4  entry certificate chain.  2 are labeled as being SHA256withRSA and the other 2 as SHA1withRSA.  By evaluating the SubjectKeyIdentifier and AuthorityKeyIdenfier fileds of each of the four certificate entries, I can see that each cert subject key "points" via their Authority Key to another Cert entry.  The PrivateKeyEntry points to one of the certs, and the final cert points to itself.  But I cannot import the cert chain into my keystore.

Comment: The "signature" tab in Windows FileExplorer Properties is only for Microsoft-format "authenticode" signatures on executables (.exe, .dll, whatever dotnet is using this year). It does **not know about jar signatures**. If `jarsigner -verify` likes it, and especially if `jarsigner -verify -verbose` shows `smk` for your entries, it's signed. If you want the **.exe** signed, you need a tool other than `jarsigner`, but I don't know what; I would start looking in the vicinity of whatever tool is creating the .exe.

Comment: Also, Java supports several keystore formats and PKCS#12 *is* a keystore; but if you want specifically a **JKS** format keystore, you can convert with `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore p12file -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore jksfile` (you don't need to specify `-deststoretype jks` because it's the default). For both PKCS#12 and JKS, `keytool -list -v` (note the `-v`) will show you the full chain of certs for the PrivateKey entry (or each entry if more than one, which is rare).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085:  Thanks.  That really helps.  Yes, I did know that you only use jarsigner for signing jar files,, and I was planning on using Mono's signcode for signing our exe.  I'm still trying to determine if our keystore is complete.  The above error message seems to indicate it is not (ie - "CertPath not validated.  Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors."